# Export server-side Prisma models for client-side usage

Tags: prisma, prisma2

Is there any automated way to export the type definitions of my models generated with `prisma generate` but without the database CRUD methods? Then I could export them as a model module and use type definitions on client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Pal.Js CLI](https://paljs.com) to generate TypeScript definitions from your `schema.prisma` file and use in any place

```sh
yarn global add @paljs/cli
//or
npm install -g @paljs/cli
```

then run

```sh
pal s typescript
```

will generate typescript file for you have all models and enums

[Docs here](https://paljs.com/cli/schema/#convert-to-typescript-definitions)